# Dart/SQFlite Import Error

Tags: dart, flutter

I am attempting to test out the SQFlite API by just creating a simple CLI. I can run the default sample app out of the same directory with both Android Studio and VS Code just fine and I can run other simple CLI programs just fine. Here is the contents of `lib/cli.dart`:

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() {
  print('SQFlite Test');    
}
```

When I run the code:

```
brianbuck$ dart --preview-dart-2 lib/cli.dart
```

I get the following error:

```
dart:ui: Error: Not found: dart:ui.
```

Here is the `pub.spec` file:

```
name: sqflite-test
description: SQFlite Test

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  http: any
  sqflite: any
```

Is there a way to let the DartVM know that I have `dart:ui` installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqflite` is for Flutter.

`dart --preview-dart-2 lib/cli.dart` is plain Dart entirely unrelated to Flutter.

If you have a dependency on `dart:ui` you can use `dart ....`, you have to use `flutter run ...`

Flutter has a customized SDK where `dart:html` and `dart:mirrors` are missing but has `dart:ui` missing in the Dart SDK.

Comment: I get that `SQFlite` is for Flutter, I was hoping it would work for plain Dart as well since the other SQLite libs don't seem to be maintained. It seems overly complicated to spin up an Android or iOS simulator just to do some exploratory type programming, but I guess the answer is, No, its not possible.

Comment: It would be possible if you could get rid of the `dart:ui` dependency. I wonder why this has to be in a database library :D, but if it uses Platform Channels, then it has a hard dependency on Flutter and can't be run without the "Platform". In this case it's just a wrapper around the Android SQLite functionality and then there is just no point in trying to use it without Flutter or even without an Android/iOS emulator.